# Read in JSON into array

Tags: python, arrays, json, list

I have the following market data in JSON format:

```
[
 {
  "date":1405728000,
  "high":0.005,
  "low":0.00406,
  "open":0.00411473,
  "close":0.00461299,
  "volume":183.76967581,
  "quoteVolume":40579.4327267,
  "weightedAverage":0.00452864
 },
 {
  /* same structure */
 },
 ...
]
```

I am trying to read it in assigning 1 variable for the close price for example:

```
import json


with open('1.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)


print data[0]["close"]
```

But this only reads in the first value for the close objects. How to put all "close" objects in 1 array?

Sorry I am amateur with arrays, so I'd like to know how to put all price types in their separate array variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
[item['close'] for item in data]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import json


with open('1.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)


print([row['close'] for row in data])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import json
data = json.load(open('1.json', 'r'))
print(data)
print(data[0]["close"])
```

If its possible, pass the absolute path for the file `1.json`

Comment: this wont print all close keys in json obj.